# A way to work on the same project on Eclipse over a several machines?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, share, dropbox

I'm a computer science student, and I'm taking `Java2EE Development` course.

a bit information about my purpose:

> I've got a final project to submission.
>
> In general, I need to develop a JavaEE servlet to manage a book library (server side),
>
> so I also need to use a Database (I've chosen MySQL), and I have to work with Hibernate framework.
>
> It's a bit large project considering the submission date (end of semester, about 4 weeks to work) and considering  the fact I have 4 another heavy courses.

Personally, I'm using `Linux Fedora 19` on my laptop, and `Microsoft Windows 7` on my desktop, which makes the business more complicated (Different path strings, for example).

I thought about creating a workspace on my Dropbox folder and link Eclipse on both machines to this path,

but then eclipse writes the configuration file into the Dropbox workspace,

Which forces both desktop and laptop eclipse use the same configuration, which make problems.

For example, the `MySQL JDBC driver jar file` in my desktop located in `"C:\Users\Billie\Downloads"` folder,

While the `MySQL JDBC driver jar file` in my laptop location in `"/home/Billie/Downloads"`.

Eclipse writes the the configuration file of the last used machine and it's makes problem in the other machine.

Any solutions? How can I use the same JAVA2EE Eclipse project over servral machines?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe git or svn could help. You could commit only the source to the repository, so each computer would have its own configuration file.

Comment: MAybe you could use an SVN repository like [this one](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/)

Comment: @jonhopkins These are eclipse plugins?

Comment: I'm sure there are Eclipse plugins for that (see @Leggy7's answer for an svn plugin). They can also be used independently of any IDE if you wish to install them on your computer. At least I know svn can. Never used git, but it's the same concept.

Comment: Any source version control tool would be great to have, don't use external absolute paths (e.g., copy all required jars into your project and refer them relatively).

Comment: in my previous comment there is a link to the website where you can download the eclipse plugin for SubVersion

Comment: @Leggy7 I saw but I cant notify multiply users, thank you

Comment: Sorry I assumed it was obvious. By the way you can find the feature description in the [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport.php)

Comment: (I used when I was studying for a project with 4 other guys and it did his dirty job quite good)

Answer (score 0):

Keep sources in VCS (like Git) and use some common build tool for managing project dependencies (Maven, Gradle, etc). Don't keep configuration in VCS - just import Maven/Gradle project into IDE. Maintaining configuration in VCS is the PITA :) .